# Cordova Android build stops by MojoBudgetService

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, chromium, mojo

My meteor app started to give an error as follows:

> I20170929-15:49:50.694(3)? 09-29 15:49:49.915  6294  6340 E chromium: [ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::BudgetService exposed by: content_browser
>
> I20170929-15:49:50.915(3)? 09-29 15:49:50.135  6294  6361 E chromium: [ERROR:BudgetService.cpp(167)] Unable to connect to the MojoBudgetService.

I have tried to add `uses-permissions` to `androidManifest`, remove all cordova plugins, reset meteor and erase cordova build cache. I am still stuck at the same point. And I have searched everywhere about this MOJO thing but there is no reference for meteor cordova app.

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution however I have deleted the current SDK and re install it. Now it is working fine when I run it in the emulator but still shows the same error when running on device.

Comment: Is this actually causing issues with your app?  I've found a couple references to this in other projects, not just Meteor ones, but this thread seems to suggest it doesn't really cause problems for Meteor Cordova apps:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9529